# Is there a way to prevent a ToolWindow from being closed?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, vsx, vspackage

Is there a way to hide the "X" closing icon of a ToolWindow or is there a way to use IVsWindowFrameNotify3's OnShow method to discard (ignore) the event?

It seems that the OnClose method is called only when VS exit. When the ToolWindow is called, the OnShow method is called with the __FRAMESHOW.FRAMESHOW_WinHidden state.

thanks

Comment: Creating a tool window that is not able to close is a sure way to upset your user base.

Comment: Well my employer want me make a VS SHELL with every menus and tool bars removed and offer our own toolbar or toolwindow. If the user hide them, there's no way, that I know, to put them back on.

Comment: I agree with Jared, maybe a better approach would be to ask a question on how to do what your employer wants you to do more efficiantly.

Comment: Perhaps you could have a menu/toolbar command that will restore the Toolwindow (similar to how the other common toolwindows in Visual Studio work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with the advice of the commentors, from what I've understood, you need to show the window when it is hidden, not closed.

Check out this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/dr._ex/archive/2004/11/07/253601.aspx